# Im having trouble passing the string '*' into argv

Tags: c, codeblocks

I would like to pass something like this: 6 3 * into argv so that

```
*argv[1] = '6'
*argv[2] = '3'
*argv[3] = '*'
```

but what ends up happening is the asterisk causes a bunch of related file names to be passed to argv, and I cant find any info on why this is...

Answer (score 2):

Use `\` to escape the `*` character when you call the program:

```
./tst 6 3 \*
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a problem between you and your shell, nothing to do with C. Launch your program like this:

```
./a.out 666 3333 "*"
```

Comment: I was also downvoted, looks like a serial downvoter ;)

Comment: @ouah: Oh well. Maybe a disengruntled Windows user who couldn't make `./` work? Or someone whose binary wasn't called `tst` or `a.out`? Endless reasons...